# ElementNotVisibleException Python/Selenium error for next page button click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to figure out how to use selenium to perform a next page click on a news release page. Here is my code that will go to the correct website and perform a search to obtain the correct news release articles topic page. This site is configured so that to see every news release on page 1 after the search has executed you must also select the More News Results button at the bottom of the page. I am able to get to the full page 1 news section without problem. Here is my code that performs the search and page clicks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.businesswire.com/portal/site/home/')
search_box_element = browser.find_element_by_id('bw-search-input')
search_box_element.clear()
search_box_element.send_keys('biotechnology')
search_box_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
search_box_element_two = browser.find_element_by_id('more-news-results')
search_box_element_two.click()
```

That part of the code works fine but I want to be able to click on the next button to move to page 2 and then page 3 and so on. Here is the code that I thought would work but it doesn't:

```
next_page_click_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("bw-paging-next")
next_page_click_element.click()
```

This portion of the code throws an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: 
element not visible
```

I have also tried using

```
next_page_click_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="more-news-pagination"]/div/div[1]/div/a')
```

but got the same error message. I have also tried using a wait by adding these lines of codes just before the next_page_click_element section.

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "bw-paging-next"))
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(element_present)
```

While this does cause the program to wait it returns this error message:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to replace `(By.ID, "bw-paging-next")` with `(By.CLASS_NAME, "bw-paging-next")`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Unfortunately that does not work. Replacing By.ID with By.CLASS_NAME returns my original Element not visible error message. The change causes no wait period to occur.

Comment: Try to execute `next_page_click_element.location_once_scrolled_into_view` before clicking

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I still get the original Element not visible error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A few words about the solution-

1. As the `Page 2`,`Page 3`,`Next` etc elements are at the bottom of the page, you have to scroll down to bring those elements within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
2. Once you scroll down you may consider to induce some `ExplicitWait` for the elements to be located properly on the HTML DOM.
3. Here is your own code with some simple tweaks which will finally scroll to the bottom of the page and click on `Next` link:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
   browser.get('http://www.businesswire.com/portal/site/home/')
   search_box_element = browser.find_element_by_id('bw-search-input')
   search_box_element.clear()
   search_box_element.send_keys('biotechnology')
   search_box_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
   search_box_element_two = browser.find_element_by_id('more-news-results')
   search_box_element_two.click()
   last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
   browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
   next_page_click_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='more-news-pagination']/div/div/div/a[text()='Next']"))
   )
   next_page_click_element.click()
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Why do you use `time.sleep()` right before `ExplicitWait`? :)

Comment: DebanjanB, Thank you for your response. Your solution worked. I really appreciate it. George

Comment: Andersson, I think you were on the right track. Thank you for your help.